# How to set initial password in BaseX

Tags: tomcat, war, basex

I use `tomcat` and have downlaoded and deployed the `basex105.war` in the folder `webapps`. I can successfully access BaseX via `localhost:8080/BaseX105/`.

Now I want to access the `DBA: Database Administration`, which requires username and password.

According to the documentation https://docs.basex.org/index.php?title=Web_Application&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop the default password for the user "admin" has been removed. **How do I set an initial password?**

Only having the *.war file, where is the script `basexhttp` or how do I start the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what the correct way is, but this solved my issue:

1. Make a new folder called "data" on root level of the unpacked war. In my case `/path/to/tomcat/webapps/BaseX105/data`. Cave: There is a data folder under `/path/to/tomcat/webapps/BaseX105/WEB-INF/data`, this does NOT work.
2. In the new data folder make a `users.xml` with the content:

   ```
   <users>
     <user name="testuser" permission="admin">
       <password algorithm="digest">
         <hash>b36dcc7c618183221ee878599cdf989a</hash>
       </password>
       <password algorithm="salted-sha256">
         <salt>7271028275349696</salt>
         <hash>eb71284c38ab22088897675065ae0f2bd5b58f1afa5273ae087604793030cfa7</hash>
       </password>
     </user>
   </users>
   ```
3. Restart `Tomcat` and you can login into the DBA with **User: testuser PW: testuser**
4. In the DBA-GUI set admin a new password. You may delete testuser from the xml.

Comment: i had the same problem today and i'll try something tomorrow, but i for now my solution was copying the former users.xml onto the new server. very unusual since newbies can't start with it

Comment: The trick is to run `basexhttp -c "PASSWORD $YOUR_PASSWORD"` in your terminal before anything else! Without quotes, you should leave the variable and enter the password in the then upcoming interactive mode. For Docker, however, this won't work, and the workaround by copying a dummy-file of users.xml, just as you suggested, is the quick'n'dirty solution.